# passing an argument to be used by instanceof

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a parser that has this construct about a zillion times:

```
if (tokens.first() instanceof CommaToken) {
    tokens.consume();
```

I would like to know how to do this:

```
if (match(CommaToken)) { ... blah ... }

private boolean match(??? tokenType) {
    if (tokens.first() instanceof tokenType) { ... blah ... }  
}
```

I'm having a wetware failure and can't figure out the class of tokenType in the method.  Another problem is that Java is treating 'tokenType' as a literal.  That is:

```
 instanceof tokenType
```

looks just like

```
 instanceof CommaToken
```

with respect to syntax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using Class objects via `class` (to get a Class object from a class reference) and `getClass()` (to get a Class object from an instance):

```
if (match(CommaToken.class)) { ... blah ... }

private boolean match(Class<?> klass) {
    if (tokens.first().getClass().equals(klass)) { ... blah ... }  
}
```

Comment: Technically, the dynamic equivalent of `instanceof` would have to be [`Class#isInstance(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object))